# Add Video Content Type Description to Document Content Type

Tags: document-library, content-type, designer

I can add/remove fields from the document content type in an asset library, but I cant seem to figure out how to get the description from the video content type. I can add a description field in general to the document type, but when I view all asset types together, there are two separate description columns. How do I add the same description field to both?